# JWT token not validating on remote server , Unable to match 'kid' Errror

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openiddict

I am using asp.net core with openiddict , for authorization i am using jwtmiddleware

```
 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
               RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
               Authority= "http://localhost"
            });
```

but for some reason its throwing this error, any help will be appreciated.

> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware[7]
>         Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501: Signature validat ion failed. Unable to match 'kid':
>   '7FG4SQ4TIATESTLI-ZDHTLRYPWIEDU_RA1FVG91D', token:
>   '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"7FG4SQ4TIATESTLI-ZDHTLRYPWIEDU_RA1FVG9
>   1D"}.{"unique_name":"asd","email":"asd","AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp":"eb93ee4
>   4-6dbf-41b8-b1d6-157e4aa23ea7","jti":"4f0f5395-e565-4489-8baf-6361d5c4cb94","usa
>   ge":"access_token","confidential":true,"scope":["offline_access","profile","emai
>   l","roles"],"sub":"9125d8c5-5739-4f46-8747-e3423a464969","azp":"firebaseApp","nb
>   f":1466997962,"exp":1466999762,"iat":1466997962,"iss":"http://localhost:5000/"}'
>   . warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.A uthorization.AuthorizeFilter'. warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.A uthorization.AuthorizeFilter'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Authority should contains the base address of your OIDC server. You should specify Authority URL with port (5000 in your case accordingly to "iss" claim in token info):

   ```
   Authority="http://localhost:5000"
   ```
2. You may disable Authority validation by setting `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false`. JwtBearerOptions contains property TokenValidationParameters, that aggregate settings about validations:

   ```
   app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
       {
           ...
           TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false}
       }
   ```

Comment: thanks for answer where to set ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false and cant we have authority on different server??

Comment: thanks in my case i just figured out i am using aws for hosting so i am having https:// domain . com on load balancer which communicates to http:// domain . com so issuer is http:// but call is made to https:// so its saying that CORS is not enabled , can we add cors to this or is there any workaround? loadbalancer is basicaly internet facing gateway which redirects it to the actual server which has no ssl

Comment: is there any resource where i can  read more about TokenValidationParameters?

Comment: just tested ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false.  its not working , without authority it doesnt work at all, i will update the exception

Comment: same exception no change

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a third party STS(not identityserver or Auth0 for example) then you can use a BackChannelHandler to make it easier to debug the http result from the middleware:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions() {
    ...
    BackchannelHttpHandler = new BackChannelHandler()
    ...
}
```

Then

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Application.API.Utilities
{
    public class BackChannelHandler : HttpMessageHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(), disposeHandler: false);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var res = await client.GetAsync(request.RequestUri);
            return res;
        }
    }   
}
```

In my case the default return type for the jwks and openid-configuration endpoints was text/html instead of application/json. By adding an Accept header when making the request from the custom handler everything works.